# Get a list of PayPal transactions

Tags: python, api, paypal, transactions, paypal-rest-sdk

I need a program for retrieving the list of transactions on my PayPal account. I tried some Python scripts, e.g. using the requests module for simply logging into PayPal with GET/POST and downloading the HTML from https://www.paypal.com/activities (shows newest transactions), but unfortunately PayPal prevents web scraping (captcha), so I didn't find a solution. There is a "TransactionSearch" API (https://api.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions), but the transactions show up with a delay of at least 3 hours (up to 48h) there... Is there a possibility to get a live version (as shown on their website) of my PayPal transactions using the PayPal API?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately according to their documentation there isn't a way to get 'live' transactions: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sync/v1/

However it does say **up to 3 hours** so you may be able to retrieve transactions sooner.

They don't state a reason for why it takes up to 3 hours for executed transactions to appear in the callable request list, however I'd assume PayPal perform security checks before even processing a transaction, let alone making the transaction accessible through an open API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Too bad... I tested it and unfortunately, the delay is at least 3 hours (normally 6h for night transactions and sometimes even more than 24 hours...).